# Docking DIV to the side of the screen

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create sidebar. Well, the design is supposed to be 3 divs. Header (Which is already done), Sidebar, and the main div.

The sidebar is intended to be on the left side on the screen, extending all the way down to the bottom (height:100%). The problem I am stuck at is that I am not able to make a 100% Div as its height only extends to the number of lines of text I have in the div.

Here is the CSS for the sidebar that I currently have:

```css
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    margin-top:36px;
    width: 300px;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #111211;
}
```

Here is the CSS code for the body that I currently have:

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#87AFC7;
}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<body>
  <div id="sidebar"> left-sidebar </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the height of the parent of the sidebar to `100%`, and in turn the parent of that. Since the sidebar is an immediate child of the `body` element, just add this to your CSS:

```
html,body { height:100%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like;

**CSS**

```
#container {
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
#top, #left, #right {
    position: absolute
}
#top {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #00b7f0
}
#left {
    top: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: #787878
}
#right {
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: #ff7e00
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/V4mxS/2/)*** is a working Live Demo.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can use pixels instead of percentages:

```
height:1000px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know

```
#sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    margin-top:36px;
    width: 300px;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #111211;
}

body, html {

hieght:100%

}
```